# Writing this PHP code in OO

Tags: php, oop

I have a PHP function which I want to convert from procedural into OOP but I am confused on how to do it. Please help.

Below is my original PHP code.

```
function smw_admin() {
global $smw, $shortname, $options;
$i=0;
if ( $_REQUEST['saved'] ) echo '<div id="message" class="updated fade"><p><strong>'.$smw.' settings saved.</strong></p></div>';
if ( $_REQUEST['reset'] ) echo '<div id="message" class="updated fade"><p><strong>'.$smw.' settings reset.</strong></p></div>';
?>

<div class="wrap rm_wrap">
<h2><?php echo $smw; ?></h2>
</div>
<form method="post">
<div class="wrap rm_wrap">
<div class="rm_opts">
    <?php foreach ($options as $value) {
switch ( $value['type'] ) {
case "open":
?>
    <?php break;
case "close":
?>
    </div>
    </div>
    <br />
    <?php break;
case "title":
?>
    <p>To easily use the <?php echo $smw;?>, you can use the menu below.</p>
    <?php break;
case 'text':
?>
    <div class="rm_input rm_text">
        <label for="<?php echo $value['id']; ?>"><?php echo $value['name']; ?></label>
        <input name="<?php echo $value['id']; ?>" id="<?php echo $value['id']; ?>" type="<?php echo $value['type']; ?>" value="<?php if ( get_settings( $value['id'] ) != "") { echo stripslashes(get_settings( $value['id'])  ); } else { echo $value['std']; } ?>" />
        <small><?php echo $value['desc']; ?></small>
        <div class="clearfix"></div>
    </div>
    <?php
break;
case 'textarea':
?>
    <div class="rm_input rm_textarea">
        <label for="<?php echo $value['id']; ?>"><?php echo $value['name']; ?></label>
        <textarea name="<?php echo $value['id']; ?>" type="<?php echo $value['type']; ?>" cols="" rows=""><?php if ( get_settings( $value['id'] ) != "") { echo stripslashes(get_settings( $value['id']) ); } else { echo $value['std']; } ?>
</textarea>
        <small><?php echo $value['desc']; ?></small>
        <div class="clearfix"></div>
    </div>
    <?php
break;
case 'select':
?>
    <div class="rm_input rm_select">
        <label for="<?php echo $value['id']; ?>"><?php echo $value['name']; ?></label>
        <select name="<?php echo $value['id']; ?>" id="<?php echo $value['id']; ?>">
            <?php foreach ($value['options'] as $option) { ?>
            <option <?php if (get_settings( $value['id'] ) == $option) { echo 'selected="selected"'; } ?>><?php echo $option; ?></option>
            <?php } ?>
        </select>
        <small><?php echo $value['desc']; ?></small>
        <div class="clearfix"></div>
    </div>
    <?php
break;
case "checkbox":
?>
    <div class="rm_input rm_checkbox">
        <label for="<?php echo $value['id']; ?>"><?php echo $value['name']; ?></label>
        <?php if(get_option($value['id'])){ $checked = "checked=\"checked\""; }else{ $checked = "";} ?>
        <input type="checkbox" name="<?php echo $value['id']; ?>" id="<?php echo $value['id']; ?>" value="true" <?php echo $checked; ?> />
        <small><?php echo $value['desc']; ?></small>
        <div class="clearfix"></div>
    </div>
    <?php break; 
case "section":
$i++;
?>
    <div class="rm_section">
    <div class="rm_title">
        <h3><img src="<?php echo plugin_dir_url(__FILE__);?>/assets/images/trans.png" class="inactive" alt="""><?php echo $value['name']; ?></h3>
        <span class="submit">
        <input name="save<?php echo $i; ?>" type="submit" value="Save changes" />
        </span>
        <div class="clearfix"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="rm_options">
    <?php break;
}
}
?>
    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="save" />
</form>
<form method="post">
    <p class="submit">
        <input name="reset" type="submit" value="Reset" />
        <input type="hidden" name="action" value="reset" />
    </p>
</form>
</div>
<?php

}
```

Here is OOP I wrote,

```
class Admin_Option{
public function smw_admin() {
        $i=0;
        if ( $_REQUEST['saved'] ) echo '<div id="message" class="updated fade"><p><strong>'.$this->smw.' settings saved.</strong></p></div>';
        if ( $_REQUEST['reset'] ) echo '<div id="message" class="updated fade"><p><strong>'.$this->smw.' settings reset.</strong></p></div>';
        ?>

        <div class="wrap rm_wrap">
            <h2><?php echo $this->smw; ?></h2>
        </div>
        <form method="post">
            <div class="wrap rm_wrap">
                <div class="rm_opts">
                    <?php foreach ($this->options as $value) {
                switch ( $value['type'] ) {
                case "open":
                ?>
                    <?php break;
                case "close":
                ?>
                </div>
            </div>
            <br />
            <?php break;
                case "title":
                ?>
            <p>To easily use the <?php echo $this->smw;?>, you can use the menu below.</p>
            <?php break;
                case 'text':
                ?>
            <div class="rm_input rm_text">
                <label for="<?php echo $value['id']; ?>"><?php echo $value['name']; ?></label>
                <input name="<?php echo $value['id']; ?>" id="<?php echo $value['id']; ?>" type="<?php echo $value['type']; ?>" value="<?php if ( get_settings( $value['id'] ) != "") { echo stripslashes(get_settings( $value['id'])  ); } else { echo $value['std']; } ?>" />
                <small><?php echo $value['desc']; ?></small>
                <div class="clearfix"></div>
            </div>
            <?php
                break;
                case 'textarea':
                ?>
            <div class="rm_input rm_textarea">
                <label for="<?php echo $value['id']; ?>"><?php echo $value['name']; ?></label>
                <textarea name="<?php echo $value['id']; ?>" type="<?php echo $value['type']; ?>" cols="" rows=""><?php if ( get_settings( $value['id'] ) != "") { echo stripslashes(get_settings( $value['id']) ); } else { echo $value['std']; } ?></textarea>
                <small><?php echo $value['desc']; ?></small>
                <div class="clearfix"></div>
            </div>
            <?php
                break;
                case 'select':
                ?>
            <div class="rm_input rm_select">
                <label for="<?php echo $value['id']; ?>"><?php echo $value['name']; ?></label>
                <select name="<?php echo $value['id']; ?>" id="<?php echo $value['id']; ?>">
                    <?php foreach ($value['options'] as $option) { ?>
                    <option <?php if (get_settings( $value['id'] ) == $option) { echo 'selected="selected"'; } ?>><?php echo $option; ?></option>
                    <?php } ?>
                </select>
                <small><?php echo $value['desc']; ?></small>
                <div class="clearfix"></div>
            </div>
            <?php
                break;
                case "checkbox":
                ?>
            <div class="rm_input rm_checkbox">
                <label for="<?php echo $value['id']; ?>"><?php echo $value['name']; ?></label>
                <?php if(get_option($value['id'])){ $checked = "checked=\"checked\""; }else{ $checked = "";} ?>
                <input type="checkbox" name="<?php echo $value['id']; ?>" id="<?php echo $value['id']; ?>" value="true" <?php echo $checked; ?> />
                <small><?php echo $value['desc']; ?></small>
                <div class="clearfix"></div>
            </div>
            <?php break; 
                case "section":
                $i++;
                ?>
            <div class="rm_section">
            <div class="rm_title">
                <h3><img src="<?php echo plugin_dir_url(__FILE__);?>/assets/images/trans.png" class="inactive" alt="" /><?php echo $value['name']; ?></h3>
                <span class="submit">
                <input name="save<?php echo $i; ?>" type="submit" value="Save changes" />
                </span>
                <div class="clearfix"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="rm_options">
            <?php break;
                }
                }
                ?>
            <input type="hidden" name="action" value="save" />
        </form>
        <form method="post">
            <p class="submit">
                <input name="reset" type="submit" value="Reset" />
                <input type="hidden" name="action" value="reset" />
            </p>
        </form>
        </div>
        <?php   
    }
}
```

Does it make sense? Am I going in the right way? Is there any other good way to do it?
Thanks

Comment: You are way off with just dumping your whole html into PHP. You best start reading into classes at [php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php)

Comment: Try to separate your code into: models (structure), views (html) and controller (logic). There are many frameworks which help you to get started like [symfony](http://symfony.com/) or [zend](http://framework.zend.com/)

Comment: This question appears to be better suited for http://codereview.stackexchange.com.

Comment: "Converting" to OOP from procedural requires a change in thinking. It's not like you can just dump it into some magical converter and solve it for you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Before you consider of moving that code to another paradigm (OO) you must first clean it up, so that it can show its true colors, what it does, what it does good (work) and what it does wrong (bugs).

So we must first **refactor** the code. For example:

**Get rid of bugs:** 
you open `<div>`s outside of the `foreach` loop and close them inside the loop and only in `case "close"`. Now since that behavior is controlled by the data structure of `$options` probably you are feeding the loop with a 'close' value at the end of the data structure and thus that possible error never manifests, but it can and the whole thing makes your code hard to read. Move the closing of the `<div>`s outside the loop where they must be since we must always close them regardless of the data structure.

**Get rid of stale code:**
Now the above change results in the `'close'` case doing nothing, and you have another case that was doing nothing the `'open'` case. Those two cases must be removed altogether - they serve no purpose other than reminding us that somewhere we have a data structure that can have an open and close value.

**Gather your inputs:**
See what your inputs are and move them to the start of the code blocks so that you can see them in a glance. Give them meaningful names, for example `$i` probably is counting section numbers so name it `$sectionNumber`. Also you see now in a specific point that you use an asset according to `__FILE__`, later when you move the code file to another relative location you will change it easily.

Also in the department of stale code you also have an unused variable, `$shortname`. We are dropping it also.

**Divide the logic from the presentation:**
No I don't hint at anything like `MVC` just get the presentation that is more than one lines out of the way so that you can see the logic of your code. Just make them into functions - even if are going to be used only from one point in the code - and move them out of the way. Later when you have cleaned out the logic you will probably make a proper template that you will feed with the data it needs etc.

see what changes and what remains the same etc

Now all of the above result in the following which is way easier to read:

```
<?php
function smw_admin() {
    global $smw, $options;
    $saved = $_REQUEST['saved'];
    $reset = $_REQUEST['reset'];
    $imageTrans = plugin_dir_url(__FILE__) . '/assets/images/trans.png';
    $sectionNumber=0;
    if ($saved) echo '<div id="message" class="updated fade"><p><strong>'.$smw.' settings saved.</strong></p></div>';
    if ($reset) echo '<div id="message" class="updated fade"><p><strong>'.$smw.' settings reset.</strong></p></div>';
?>

<div class="wrap rm_wrap">
    <h2><?php echo $smw; ?></h2>
</div>
<form method="post">
    <div class="wrap rm_wrap">
        <div class="rm_opts">
            <?php
            foreach ($options as $value) {
                switch ( $value['type'] ) {
                case "open":
                   break;
                case "close":
                   break;
                case "title":
                    echo "<p>To easily use the $smw, you can use the menu below.</p>";
                    break;
                case 'text':
                    render_div_rm_input_rm_text($value);
                    break;
                case 'textarea':
                    render_rm_input_rm_textarea($value);
                    break;
                case 'select':
                    render_rm_input_rm_select($value);
                    break;
                case "checkbox":
                    render_rm_input_rm_checkbox($value);
                    break;
                case "section":
                    $sectionNumber++;
                    render_rm_section($imageTrans, $value, $sectionNumber);
                    break;
                }
            }
            ?>
        </div>
    </div>
    <br />
    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="save" />
</form>
<form method="post">
    <p class="submit">
        <input name="reset" type="submit" value="Reset" />
        <input type="hidden" name="action" value="reset" />
    </p>
</form>
</div>
<?php
}
```

and various functions like:

```
function render_rm_section($imageTrans, $value, $i)
{
    ?>
    <div class="rm_section">
    <div class="rm_title">
        <h3><img src="<?php echo $imageTrans; ?>" class="inactive" alt="""><?php echo $value['name']; ?></h3>
                    <span class="submit">
                    <input name="save<?php echo $i; ?>" type="submit" value="Save changes"/>
                    </span>

        <div class="clearfix"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="rm_options">
    <?php
}
```

at that point you could start the OO way - although you should refactor it more for example by not echoing the result directly but instead getting the result as a return value,  consolidating more the code base etc.

A 1st phase example could be:

```
Class SmwPage {

private options;
private $smw;
private $imageTrans;

function __construct($options, $smw) {
    $this->options = $options;  
    $this->smw = $smw;
    $this->imageTrans = plugin_dir_url(__FILE__) . '/assets/images/trans.png';
}

function render() {
    // render the beggining
    // the same code as before only we now operate with $this-> at the class member variables (properties)
    foreach ($this->options as $value) {
        // switch statement here        
    }
    // render the end
}
```

with a usage of:

```
$smwPage = new SmwPage($options, $smw);
$smwPage->render();
```

Of course the above class would need to change

1. every time you would need to add a new option and
2. every time we need to change how an option is rendered

so in the next step you will want to change the data structure to a collection of objects that each knows how to `render()` itself. Then the render of `SmwPage` would be only a loop through the collection of those objects and a call to their `render()` method.

Comment: this is an incredible answer to such a poorly formed question...